# How big is a cudaStream_t?

Tags: c++, cuda, portability, void-pointers, cuda-streams

I have inherited some code that basically does stuff like this:

```
void *stream;
cudaStreamCreate((cudaStream_t *)&stream);
```

Looking at `targets/x86_64-linux/driver_types.h` for CUDA 8, I see:

```
typedef __device_builtin__ struct CUStream_st *cudaStream_t;
```

As far as I understand it, the cast will work, but I worry about how future-proof this may be, and also if it is safe when the code is ported to ARM. How dangerous is the above code? Does the `__device_builtin__` affect anything?

(Note: I plan to talk to the developer directly and tell them to use `cudaStream_t` throughout and `#include <cuda_runtime.h>`, so I am hoping to clarify the technical issues here.)

Comment: I don't see a problem with that code.  It's kind of the same as `void * mem = malloc(5*sizeof(int));`.  I would say it is actually rather safe because dereferencing a pointer to `void` will trigger a warning.  The problem I see is verbosity because you now have to litter your code with casts to `cudaStream_t*`.

Comment: The cast is guaranteed to work by the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#5

Comment: @HenriMenke Does the `__device_builtin__` attribute affect things, though?

Comment: That is just an attribute which influences code generation for `ptxas` (just like `__host__` and `__device__` for functions).

Comment: This of course depends on CUDA definining `cudaStream_t` to be a pointer type. If that should change, the code could break.  It might be that CUDA provides a guarantee that `cudaStream_t` will always be a pointer type, but I couldn't put my finger on such a guarantee.  I'm unsure why someone would choose this coding approach over `cudaStream_t stream;`

Comment: @RobertCrovella "I'm unsure why someone would choose this coding approach" I often ask myself this with much of the code I get passed! In this case, I think the handles are cached in non-CUDA code, so perhaps they didn't want to pollute the header file, but then again there are already massive amounts of `#ifdef USE_CUDA`s.

Answer (score 4):

> How big is a `cudaStream_t`?

Like you've observed,

```
typedef __device_builtin__ struct CUStream_st *cudaStream_t;
```

So it's a pointer, and has the size of a pointer, i.e. 64 bits on typical architectures today but different sizes on other architectures. But do you really need to utilize that information? I would guess not.

> As far as I understand it, the cast will work, but I worry about how future-proof this may be

Then make it:

```
cudaStream_t stream;
cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
```

or use the [C++'ish API wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers), e.g.:

```
auto device = cuda::device::current::get();
auto stream = device.create_stream(cuda::stream::sync);
```

where that's abstracted away, and `stream_t` is a wrapper, not a pointer, anyway (caveat: I'm the author of the wrapper library.)

What I'd worry about is not incompatibility, but rather avoiding invalid assumptions. And, indeed, **you should not assume cudaStream_t is a pointer - just treat it as something opaque.**

> and also if it is safe when the code is ported to ARM. How dangerous is the above code?

It's dangerous, but not because of the porting, but like I said, because of the invalid assumption. It would be less dangerous with, say,

```
static_assert(sizeof(void*) == sizeof(cudaStream_t),
    "Unexpected size of cudaStream_t - not the same as void *");
```

but why are you insisting on the `void *`, really?